# checkout in a git feature branch with "SCM Sync configuration plugin"

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control

Is it possible to checkout a feature-branch in "SCM Sync configuration plugin"  ?

It seems to push all changes in "master" branch every time jenkins configuration is changing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can’t checkout to another branch for a certain configure item.

If you want SCM sync with other branches, you can changes or add other branches.

[image].